# cakephp datetime input value not displayed

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I've created an input-field for a datetime and I also get the value set, but I've got no value displayed:

HTML:

```
<input name="data[Date][dat_date_time]" dateformat="DMY" timeformat="24" type="datetime-local" value="2015-08-26 20:23:44" id="DateDatDateTime" required="required">
```

in Browser:

[image]

can anybody help me, why the date and the time is not displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the letter T before your time:

```
<input name="data[Date][dat_date_time]" dateformat="DMY" timeformat="24" type="datetime-local" value="2015-08-26T20:23:44" id="DateDatDateTime" required="required">
```

More information: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime-local.html